# ¿Qué puede producir el error siguiente: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet?

Tags: oracle, eclipse, jpql

(Persistencia y JPQL)
Estoy intentando recibir una lista de la base de datos de Oracle desde Eclipse. ¿Qué puede ocasionarme este error?

> (org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet)

```
List result = em.createQuery(
                    "SELECT e.VALOR " +
                    "FROM TIPOINCIDENCIA e JOIN INCIDENCIA p " +
                    "WHERE idTipo = ID AND e.ID = ?1" ) // without return class type
                    .setParameter(1, myInt).getResultList();
            
            int count = 0;
            for (Iterator i = result.iterator(); i.hasNext();) {
            Object[] values = (Object[]) i.next();
            System.out.println(++count + ": " +
            values[0] + ", " + values[1]);
            }
```

Comment: ¿Qué significa el `1` al lado del marcador?: `WHERE idTipo = ID AND e.ID = ?1`

Comment: el numero de parametro a introducir (practicamente me lo exigio al compilar en un error.

Comment: Sí sí eso es correcto, no conocía esa forma. Lo que sospecho es que tu instrucción SQL es errónea en sí misma, por ejemplo, no aparece en qué columna debe ocurrir el `JOIN`. También, usa los alias siempre, en todas las columnas, por claridad y para evitar errores de duplicidad... ¿Esa consulta funciona en tu SGBD si la copias / pegas, agregando un valor de prueba?

Comment: @gbianchi parece que esa forma es correcta. Se llama [*Positional Parameters in Queries*](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnbrg.html#bnbri)

Comment: Tu consulta, respetando el estándar SQL, debería estar escrita así: **`"SELECT e.VALOR " + "FROM TIPOINCIDENCIA AS e JOIN INCIDENCIA AS p " + "ON p.idTipo = e.ID WHERE e.ID = ?1"`** Asumiendo que el  `JOIN` debe ocurrir entre las columnas `idTipo` de la tabla `INCIDENCIA` y `ID` de la tabla `TIPOINCIDENCIA`, como ves, he usado el alias con cada columna. Si sigue dando error, copia y pega la consulta para probarla en el SGBD, cambiando el `?1` por un valor real.

Comment: ahhh es algo re particular de esa libreria de Java.. ok.. me desdigo..  @A.Cedano

Comment: Este sitio funciona por preguntas. Una vez resuelto este problema, debes abrir una nueva pregunta con el nuevo problema, indicando el mensaje de error. Stackoverflow no es un foro.

Comment: correcto! GRACIAS! era toda la consulta....

Comment: Recuerden marcar la respuesta como aceptada (asumo que es la que puso @A.Cedano abajo. :)

Answer (score 1):

Cuando una consulta falla, considera probarla en el SGBD, cambiando los parámetros por un valor real.

La actual consulta parece errónea desde el punto de vista sintáctico.

Prueba de este modo:

```
List result = em.createQuery(
                "SELECT e.VALOR " +
                "FROM TIPOINCIDENCIA AS e INNER JOIN INCIDENCIA AS p " +
                "ON p.idTipo = e.ID WHERE e.ID = ?1" ) 
                .setParameter(1, myInt).getResultList();
```

Asumo que el `JOIN` debe ocurrir entre las columnas `idTipo` de la tabla `INCIDENCIA` y `ID` de la tabla `TIPOINCIDENCIA`.

Como ves, he usado el alias con cada columna, por razones de claridad y para evitar errores en caso de que las tablas tengan columnas con el mismo nombre.